# Slowly Phase out an old web application + replace incrementally

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I am trying to come up with a plan for phasing out an old (8-10+ years old) web application codebase and incrementally build a new codebase alongside it.

I am hoping to find a way to allow requests to come through and then route them to the appropriate codebase based on the URI.

The best way to describe it would be to give an example. To start I want to iteratively build out articles:

```
# route it to the new web application codebase
/articles/:id:
# everything else besides /articles* goes to the old codebase.
/*
```

I have control over the server architecture (apart from the application language), which right now uses php + apache + varnish. So any technologies that could help accomplish this would be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a solid look at mod_rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

It gives you quite a bit of flexibility in modifying urls on the fly, while still keeping the logic out of your application layer.  This decouples this intermediate state from either code-base, allowing them both to be agnostic of each other.